# Count instances of a string, excluding when timestamps <1min apart

Tags: bash, shell

I am beginner in coding. I have a script that will grep for specific word in a file. i need a count of its occurrences, but the word i am looking is, cascading. so i want to ignore occurrence if repeated again with in less than 1 min. but also if the device that occurred is different from the first occurrence, it should not be ignored
For example: file1.txt

```
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.001 There is a error 12345
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.009 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.500 There is a error 12345
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.601 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:46.899 There is a error 12345
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:46.905 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:49.203 There is a error 12345
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:49.491 error 12345 is reported on device-6
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:52.703 There is a error 12345
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:29:52.991 error 12345 is reported on device-6
```

result was

```
grep -c 12345 file1.txt
10
```

Result that i got  = 10

Result that i need = 3

how can i ignore repeated occurrences based of time stamp.

Comment: FYI, the "snippet" mechanism is for StackSnippets, which are our local alternative to JSFiddle, for code that can run in a browser. Use the `{}` button to format other code.

Comment: That said, this doesn't look like a "specific character exists" exclusion rule, but rather, one that involves comparing timestamps. I've edited the title to reflect your actual intent.

Comment: Do you need to handle the boundary between days? Much easier to just punt on that and consider a message in the last few milliseconds of one day and one in the first few milliseconds of the next to be two distinct messages.

Comment: Also, if you have 15 messages each 30 seconds apart, do you want to log every other one (since only the excluded messages are less than 60 seconds away from a logged message), or only the first and no others (since it's less than 60 seconds from the prior matching message)?

Comment: Since `2018.09.06` has not occurred yet, are we to take that format as representing `year.day.month`? (which you will need to rearrange for conversion to seconds since epoch with `date -d`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much do you care about the "within 1 minute of each other" part?  If it is sufficient to say "ignore multiple occurrences within a specific minute" this is fairly straightforward.

First get a list of all the 'error xyz is reported' lines

```
$ grep "error 12345 is reported" tfile.txt
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.009 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:45.601 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:46.905 error 12345 is reported on device-1
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:27:49.491 error 12345 is reported on device-6
file .txt    2018.09.06 21:29:52.991 error 12345 is reported on device-6
```

Then reduce these using sed down to `HH:MM device-number` format

```
$ grep reported tfile.txt | sed 's/.*\(..:..\):.*reported on \(.*\)/\1 \2/'
21:27 device-1
21:27 device-1
21:27 device-1
21:27 device-6
21:29 device-6
```

Then find the unique entries

```
$ grep reported tfile.txt | sed 's/.*\(..:..\):.*reported on \(.*\)/\1 \2/' | uniq
21:27 device-1
21:27 device-6
21:29 device-6
```

And finally count them

```
$ grep reported tfile.txt | sed 's/.*\(..:..\):.*reported on \(.*\)/\1 \2/' | uniq | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to parse out the timestamp, do some date-time math (always somewhat hard, but at least you're probably not crossing timezones, though you may be crossing daylight-savings times periodically, and I don't think you have enough information there to tell when that happens).  This likely means a simple grep won't suffice, you'll need to read each line in bash, parse it out, and track it.

You'll then want something like sed or awk to parse the line. As long as you're doing that anyway, you may want to just use awk for the whole thing.  I've never used awk for timestamp management, though I see man pages for it, so it should be able to handle that.  The rest is tracking the device name against timestamp, awk manages that just fine.

I would suggest, however, reaching for a higher-level language for this. Whether perl, python, ruby, they should all be able to handle this fairly easily.